# how can I reconnect DSL in cisco router 877w

Tags: networking, router, adsl

I've configured ADSL and added new public LAN IPs for the router. How can I reconnect DSL connection and apply the new configuration without executing the command reload?

These are the commands I am using for DSL configuration:

```
 config terminal
 interface dialer 0
 ppp chap hostname User
 ppp chap password 0 Pass
 exit
 exit
 wr mem
```

and these are the commands I am using for adding IP addresses:

```
configure t
interface vlan 1
ip address xx.xx.xx.xx 255.255.255.252 Secondary
exit
wr mem
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just try `shut / no shut` on dialer port.

```
conf t
 interface dialer 0
  shut #may be wait few seconds after this
  no shut
end
```

And since this is not programming related, so, I am voting to close this (probably to superuser)